# Is there any way to make a GUI myself using NodeJS without downloading packages for it?

Tags: node.js, user-interface

The reason for no packages is because my company is very tight about what packages can be downloaded and approval can take up to two weeks, but I wanted to make a small application for myself to track things in a way I like. Is there a way to make a GUI without downloading external packages to NodeJS?

Comment: Generally you wouldn't make a GUI in Node. Assuming this would be web based, yes, you can do it from scratch.

Comment: I should just do web based then. What would be a good accompaniment to making a GUI with Node code? This is cause I wanted to make a RasbPi interface for my hue lights at home, and I have code in NodeJS for them

Comment: You would jut build out the interface using good ol' HTML/JS/CSS and communicate with your node server over an API. It's still a bit unclear what you're asking as you don't build GUIs in Node, which runs on a server. None of my business, but why would your company care if you downloaded packages to operate your home? Need a lot more details and clarity here.

Comment: The second question in the comments is for my personal IoT. The main question was for company computer. Also I'm still a noob with NodeJS, but also the most experienced person in the department. It kinda sucks

Comment: Just curious why your company controls what technology you use for your Raspberry Pi at home?  Sounds odd.  Just make a web interface and let the browser be your GUI.  I have a web interface on a Raspberry Pi that controls some HVAC.  Works great.  FYI, a nice tool for making a GUI using node.js is Electron.  There are commercial products built in Electron.

Comment: They don't control my at home stuff. At first I was asking about what I could make on my work computer to track my projects and time (excel or such just doesn't work for me cause I process weird). I changed to asking about RasperryPi because I did want to also make a GUI on my at home one, and figured I'd ask in the same question as well